# Watson Conversation: adding one year to current date

Tags: watson-conversation

Goal: Print the current year "2017" and the following year "2018".
I can currently print the current year using below, but cannot print the following year.

```
"Current_Year": "<? now().reformatDateTime('yyyy')  ?>"
"Next_Year": "<? now().reformatDateTime('yyyy+1')  ?>"
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to convert it into Integer and then add 1 to it.

```
 "Next Year":" <?now().reformatDateTime('yyyy').toInt()+1 ?>"
```

Now you will get 2018 as result.

Comment: Hm...I'm still getting an error when I put the code here. Error is saying "expecting string, number, null, true, false, etc but getting undefined" "context": {
    "Next_Year":<? now().reformatDateTime('yyyy').toInt()+1 ?>
  }

Comment: It works now, thank you! I forgot the quotes around the second part.